# Non valid passport with US visa taken by authorities. Is there a solution?

Tags: visas, usa

I had two passports (1 valid, and another one issued by the same country with the same data and photo as the first one, but this one was cancelled, with a valid US visa). I carried both of them (I had a burglary recently in my flat and police in my country made fun of me, but this is a different story. That's thee reason I carried both passports with me).

At border crossing while I talked with my fellow passenger, I handed over the non-valid passport by mistake. After questioning (my arguments were not accepted) the non valid passport with the US visa was taken from me with a receipt and a promise that they would send it back to my local police station through the foreign ministry in my home country.

After almost 6 months, I am still without my passport with the US visa. What can I do? The visa FAQ on the US State Department's website deals only with lost and stolen passports with US visas, not with passports taken by legitimate police authorities in recognized countries. Thank you for any help.

Comment: There is nothing you can do on the USA side of things, meaning US Embassy will only consider stolen/missing passport/visa. **They are not interested in the details of your problems with authorities**.You will have to resolve that with your own country.  You will have to get a police report to show that passport is missing/stolen, then apply for a new US visa. They will void the old visa in their system, however it's not guaranteed they'll issue you a new one. They will interview you just like a new applicant. Note: if they suspect that the passport was confiscated for fraud you're done.

Comment: Your story sounds convoluted and my hunch is if the US guys hear it as you have stated here, your chances of getting a new visa will be slim and none. Basically you were using an invalid passport, no embassy would like that.

Comment: What is your home country?  What country took your passport?  Can you get help from the authorities that gave you the receipt?  Can you get help from the embassy of your home country in the country that took your passport?

Comment: Do you mean that your US visa was in an _expired_ passport, or that it was in a _fake_ passport?

Comment: @Michael Hampton - Expired passport for god sake :)

Comment: @The Zealot/  In my whole life (I am approaching 50 years of age) I had only few traffic fines. If I was fraudster, or worse,  they will I guess know that anyway, and never issue visa to me..

Comment: @TheZealot why don't you make your comment an answer; it certainly covers all the bases. Ping me and I'll upvote:)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do on the USA side of things, meaning US Embassy will only consider stolen/missing passport/visa. They are not interested in the details of your problems with authorities.You will have to resolve that with your own country.

[The guidance for lost/missing passports on VISA FAQ on US State Department website still applies](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/lost-stolen-visas.html).

You will have to get a police report to show that passport is missing/stolen, then apply for a new US visa. They will void the old visa in their system, however it's not guaranteed they'll issue you a new one. They will interview you just like a new applicant. Note: if they suspect that the passport was confiscated for fraud you're done.